# Best way to do expensive computations in a React Native app

Tags: react-native, performance

Let's say I want to make an app that shows the result of an expensive computation like the multiplication of 400x400 matrices for example. What would be the fastest way to make these computations in a React Native app ?

My first thought was using something like Rust and compiling it to WASM, but this doesn't seem possible in React Native. I also saw that using the Hermes engine could make the app faster, but I don't know if that would be fast enough this case.

Also, if I used Java and Swift to use "native" code on the phone, would that make any difference in the speed of the computation ?

Comment: Would not recommend at all to do such things in the front-end anyways.. you'd need some sort of backend to do so

Comment: Like doing the computations on a server ? Or is there a way to do backend stuff in React Native ? I would prefer if the thing could stay offline

Comment: [useTransition](https://react.dev/reference/react/useTransition) is for this purpose.